# when a new Screen is called then will the old screen be disposed?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am coding newly in android libgdx framework.
I got a basic doubt if i navigate from one screen to another will the old screen be disposed or wait in paused or hide state??

please help me out with this doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ScreenAndGameClasses:

> Note that Screen's dispose() method is never called automatically- when ApplicationListener's dispose() method is called, Game calls screen.hide() instead.

Comment: Thanx that did solved my problem of 'screen call and memory leaks' at stretch .

Comment: Can we call the screen which is in "hide state" with updated values using that screen's obj???

Answer (score 1):

It depends on you, if you are move from one screen to another screen and if you used `finish()` method with intent then first screen will be `disposed` otherwise it will be in `paused` state.

Comment: am not using intents am using a call similar to it like
'obj.setScreen(new Gamescreen2(obj));'

Answer (score 0):

With ur approach it wont.All the graphics and objects will be there in memory untill u dispose them explicitly.

If u dispose them then make sure to load them again